# Problems installing Steam on CentOS 8 Stream

Tags: linux, centos, steam

I'm having a problem installing Steam on CentOS 8 using RPMFusion repositories.

```
[imptovskii@imptovskii-pc ~]$ sudo dnf install steam
CentOS-8 - AppStream                            7.6 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00    
CentOS-8 - Base                                  15 kB/s | 3.9 kB     00:00    
CentOS-8 - Extras                               5.5 kB/s | 1.5 kB     00:00    
CentOS-8 - PowerTools                           6.9 kB/s | 4.3 kB     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 -  31 kB/s |  34 kB     00:01    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64   23 kB/s |  21 kB     00:00    
google-chrome                                   6.6 kB/s | 1.3 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for EL 8 - Free tainted               32 kB/s | 9.0 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for EL 8 - Free - Updates             20 kB/s | 3.7 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for EL 8 - Nonfree tainted            35 kB/s | 9.2 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for EL 8 - Nonfree - Updates         9.4 kB/s | 3.7 kB     00:00    
Ошибка: 
 Проблема: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides gamemode(x86-32) needed by steam-1.0.0.62-1.el8.i686
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

In case it matters, 'Ошибка' is Russian for 'Error' and 'Проблема' means 'Problem'.

Comment: »nothing provides gamemode(x86-32)« : There is a 32bits package available from Fedora 29 https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/29/Everything/x86_64/Packages/g/gamemode-1.2-3.fc29.i686.rpm .. which installs OK with `dnf`, but some conflict between `glibc.i686,  glibc32.x86.64` appears with `dnf install steam`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only tested installing it, not running it. But this method does install it without errors:

1. Install the i686 package of glibc, so that gamemode does not automatically fetch "glibc32":

`dnf install glibc-2*el8*.i686`

2. Install the 32bit gamemode from Fedora 29 repo:

`dnf install https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/29/Everything/x86_64/Packages/g/gamemode-1.2-3.fc29.i686.rpm`

3. Install steam:

`dnf install steam`

Comment: @Imptovskii: If you already installed gamemode and got the odd **glibc32** : 1. `# rpm -e --nodeps glibc32` .... 2. `# dnf install glibc.i686` ... Then steam installs OK.

Comment: Thanks, i will try a little later, and I will say the results.

Comment: Many thanks! Everything is working!I will keep this manual, because it is useful!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Fedora repos does work, but means you won't be getting updates and are using a sort of Franken setup which is probably not what you're looking for since you're running CentOS.

You do need to install glibc-i686 so the first step of the selected answer does not change:

```
dnf install glibc-2*el8*.i686
```

But I would recommend as the next step using the bundled Flatpak repos CentOS supports nowadays to install steam.

```
flatpak install flathub com.valvesoftware.Steam
```

Flatpaks are officially supported and you will get updates with this method. It is what I would strongly recommend instead of using RPMs from Fedora 29.